# Disable default zfcUser routes?

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm using `zfcUser` and I was wondering if its possible to disable the default routes, such as `zfcUser/login`, `zfcUser/register`, etc because I do not want to expose them.

I looked at the `zfcuser.global.php` but there seems to be no such option?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply override the configuration by setting a null controller or an unmatchable routing configuration.

Solution 1: override the `zfcuser` controller invokable:

```php
// YourApp\Module#getConfig() or config/autoload/zfcuser.override.global.php

return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'zfcuser' => null,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Solution 2: overriding routing configuration by using your own route config (hacky, discouraged):

```php
// YourApp\Module#getConfig() or config/autoload/zfcuser.override.global.php

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'zfcuser' => array(
                // changing to hostname route - using an unreachable hostname
                'type' => 'Hostname',
                // minimum possible priority - all other routes come first.
                'priority' => ~PHP_INT_MAX,
                'options' => array(
                    // foo.bar does not exist - never matched
                    'route' => 'foo.bar',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => null,
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),

                // optional - just if you want to override single child routes:
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'login' => array(
                        'options' => array(
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => null,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'authenticate' => array(
                        'options' => array(
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => null,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'logout' => array(
                        'options' => array(
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => null,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'register' => array(
                        'options' => array(
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => null,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'changepassword' => array(
                        'options' => array(
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => null,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'changeemail' => array(
                        'options' => array(
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => null,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: It seems your answer was cut short; can you post the NullRoute suggestion again?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan the `NullRoute` suggestion is actually way too hacky. I made up my mind and removed it, since it's long and it has no benefit compared to the solutions posted above.

Comment: FYI, the first solution should be fine, since it basically removes the `zfcuser` controller completely, which is also safe to use.

Comment: I see, using the first suggestion I still get the following back on the zfcuser routes: The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

Controller:
    zfcuser(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: zfcuser) -- is there any way to remove/hide this?

Comment: If you don't want to reach that point, you need to disable the routes too. That's a 404 error anyway, it differs only in the exception message, so your end customer won't see it once you customized the 404 views.

Comment: I just realised though, setting 'zfcuser' controller to null invalidates the login process and such. Basically I want to use the login widget but not allow the zfcuser-routes to be accessed

Comment: Then you need to use the second solution, but with your own routing configuration to still allow login/logout. The login widget by zfcuser still uses the zfcuser routes as far as I know.